# Restrict String field, to not accept true/false as the field value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

Any ideas, how should I restrict String field in the Request Body, to not be able to have true or false as it's value. Couldn't find anything similar here. Ideally 400 Bad request would be the best solution. I am hoping that there is something  from the javax.validation

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class FeeGroupBody {

   @JsonProperty("ext_group_id")
   @NotNull
   private String groupExtId;

   @JsonProperty("ext_fee_id")
   @NotNull
   private String feeExtId;
}
```

Comment: Not totally positive what you're trying to do, but I would consider using the javax.validation package.  We use the [hibernate implementation](https://hibernate.org/validator/).  In our application we have a `@Controller` that accepts a `Command Object` that has its validation rules as annotations.  You'll need to write your own validation rule where that field cannot be true/false strings, consider doing a `.equalsIgnoreCase()` and then in the controller you check to see if there were validation errors and return the http response you want.

Comment: You can use @Pattern

Comment: @hooknc Yeah that would do the thing but I was hoping for some more let's say shorter solution, like using some annotation from the  javax.validation package.

Comment: @Tarun yeah pattern is not a bad idea. The thing is, if  I place null, or some number i.e 57, spring validation will automatically return bad request, but somehow it is not the case with the boolean values.

Comment: Validation is quite tricky.  We had to do some work to make validation work in in a specific order:  null checks, data type, data values, persistence checks.  Where if any of those levels fail, then the next level isn't even checked.  All the type, value, and persistence validators have to ignore null values for this strategy to work.  So, I guess what I'm saying, is that there isn't a 'easy' way to do validation or better yet, I've never seen an 'easy' way to do validation.

Comment: @Milos you can provide custom implementation of  the annotation , but are you looking for st shorter?

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani Custom annotation is a good idea, but I think I am gonna go with the Pattern, as it seems to be the fastest way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested you can do this using a custom annotation and custom validator. You would begin with the custom annotation:

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotTrueOrFalseStringValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotTrueOrFalseString {
    String message() default "String value is one of the following invalid values: true or false";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And then the custom validator:

```java
public class NotTrueOrFalseStringValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotTrueOrFalseString, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("true", value) &&
            !org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("false", value);
    }

}
```

Then you just need to apply it in your model:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class FeeGroupBody {

   @JsonProperty("ext_group_id")
   @NotNull
   @NotTrueOrFalseString
   private String groupExtId;

   @JsonProperty("ext_fee_id")
   @NotNull
   @NotTrueOrFalseString
   private String feeExtId;
}
```

You can read more about custom validators at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator.